# Solving CHRL4 on code chef (CHEF and Way) in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to solve this question in Haskell but the codechef compiler keeps on saying it is the wrong answer. The question is as follows:

After visiting a childhood friend, Chef wants to get back to his home. Friend lives at the first street, and Chef himself lives at the N-th (and the last) street. Their city is a bit special: you can move from the X-th street to the Y-th street if and only if 1 <= Y - X <= K, where K is the integer value that is given to you. Chef wants to get to home in such a way that the product of all the visited streets' special numbers is minimal (including the first and the N-th street). Please, help him to find such a product.
Input

The first line of input consists of two integer numbers - N and K - the number of streets and the value of K respectively. The second line consist of N numbers - A1, A2, ..., AN respectively, where Ai equals to the special number of the i-th street.
The output should be modulo 1000000007

Input

4 2

1 2 3 4

Output

8

The solution I used is as follows:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)


findMinIndex x index minIndex n
      | index == n = minIndex
      | (x!!index) < (x!!minIndex) = findMinIndex x (index+1) index n
      | otherwise = findMinIndex x (index+1) minIndex n


minCost []     _ = 1
minCost (x:xs) k = let indexList = take k xs
                       minIndex = findMinIndex indexList 0 0 (length indexList)
                   in x * minCost(drop minIndex xs) k

main :: IO()
main = do
       t <- B.getContents
       let inputs = B.lines t
       let firstLine = inputs !! 0
       let secondLine = inputs !! 1
       let [n,k] = map (fst . fromJust . B.readInt) $ B.split ' ' firstLine
       let specialNums = reverse $ map (fst . fromJust . B.readInteger) $ B.split ' ' secondLine
       putStrLn $ show ((minCost specialNums k) `mod` 1000000007)
```

---

It worked for the given test case and a few other test cases I tries out. But it is not being accepted by codechef. I followed the editorial for the problem and made it. Basically starting from the last number in the list of special numbers the program search it's immediate k predecessors and finds the minimum one in that range and multiplies it with the current value and so on till the beginning of the list

Comment: I don't know how much of a hint you want, but your algorithm does not always find the best (= minimum product) path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm doesn't always give the smallest product for all the inputs, e.g. this one:

```
5 2
3 2 3 2 3
```

The [editorial](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/37605/chrl4-editorial) explained the problem throughout, you really should read it again.

This problem is basically a shortest path problem, streets are vertices, possible movements from street to street are edges of the graph, the weight of an edge is determined by the special value of the tail alone. While the total movement cost is defined as the product but not the sum of all the costs,  the question can be normalized by taking logarithms of all the special values, since

> a * b = exp(log(a) + log(b))

Given log is monotonically increasing function, the minimal product is just the minimal sum of logarithms.

In editorial the editor picked Dijkstra's algorithm, but after taking the log transformation, it will be a standard shortest path problem and can be solved with any shortest path algorithm you like.

There are many implementations of Dijkstra's algorithm in Haskell, I found two on Hackage and one [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm#Haskell). The parsing and graph initializing code is straight forward.

```
import           Control.Monad      (foldM)
import           Control.Monad.ST
import           Data.Array
import           Data.Array.MArray
import           Data.Array.ST
import           Data.Function      (on)
import           Data.IntMap.Strict as M
import           Data.List          (groupBy)
import           Data.Set           as S

-- Code from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm#Haskell
dijkstra :: (Ix v, Num w, Ord w, Bounded w) => v -> v -> Array v [(v,w)] -> (Array v w, Array v v)
dijkstra src invalid_index adj_list = runST $ do
  min_distance <- newSTArray b maxBound
  writeArray min_distance src 0
  previous <- newSTArray b invalid_index
  let aux vertex_queue =
        case S.minView vertex_queue of
          Nothing -> return ()
          Just ((dist, u), vertex_queue') ->
            let edges = adj_list Data.Array.! u
                f vertex_queue (v, weight) = do
                  let dist_thru_u = dist + weight
                  old_dist <- readArray min_distance v
                  if dist_thru_u >= old_dist then
                    return vertex_queue
                  else do
                    let vertex_queue' = S.delete (old_dist, v) vertex_queue
                    writeArray min_distance v dist_thru_u
                    writeArray previous v u
                    return $ S.insert (dist_thru_u, v) vertex_queue'
            in
            foldM f vertex_queue' edges >>= aux
  aux (S.singleton (0, src))
  m <- freeze min_distance
  p <- freeze previous
  return (m, p)
  where b = bounds adj_list
        newSTArray :: Ix i => (i,i) -> e -> ST s (STArray s i e)
        newSTArray = newArray

shortest_path_to :: (Ix v) => v -> v -> Array v v -> [v]
shortest_path_to target invalid_index previous =
  aux target [] where
    aux vertex acc | vertex == invalid_index = acc
                   | otherwise = aux (previous Data.Array.! vertex) (vertex : acc)


-- Code I wrote
instance Bounded Double where
    minBound = -1e100
    maxBound = 1e100

constructInput :: Int -> Int -> M.IntMap Integer -> Array Int [(Int, Double)]
constructInput n k specMap =
    let
        specMap' = fmap (log . fromIntegral) specMap
        edges = [(src, [(dest, specMap' M.! dest) | dest <- [src+1..src+k], dest <= n]) | src <- [1..n]]
    in
        array (1, n) edges

main :: IO ()
main = do
    rawInput <- getContents
    let
        [l, l'] = lines rawInput
        [n,k] = fmap read . words $ l
        specs = fmap read . words $ l'
        specMap = M.fromList $ [1..n] `zip` specs
        adj_list = constructInput n k specMap
        (_, previous) = dijkstra 1 0 adj_list
        path = shortest_path_to n 0 previous
        weight = (product $ fmap (specMap M.!) path) `mod` 1000000007
    print weight
```

PS: My program scores 30 with a lot of TLE (short for "Too Long Execution" I guess) on CodeChief, for the full mark you may have to try it yourself and get a better solution.

Comment: Thank you. I realized this after a few days and corrected the code. Now it works. Thank you again

Comment: Apologies for the late communication. I compiled this code , and i always get an error "Non type-variable argument” on " f vertex_queue (v, weight) = do” highlighted red. What could be the issue?